# How to use "AXSubrole", "AXRoleDescription" in applescript?

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc, applescript-excel

Can we use "AXSubrole", "AXRoleDescription" in applescript? If yes, what is the correct way? I tried following code.

```
-- open Excel -> VB Editor
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        tell window 1
            if ((value of attribute "AXSubrole") is equal to "AXStandardWindow") Then
             -- do something here
            end if 
        end tell        
    end tell
end tell
```

But gives error "Can't get AXSubrole".  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, we can. The code is correct.

Comment: ya thanks @vadian, the problem was "window 1" was referring to something else. How can we know the correct index of a particular ui element?

Comment: You can check `exists window x` or `exists attribute "y"`

Comment: ok thanks......